# $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n!e -[n!e] $

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $$l = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n!e -[n!e] $$
Here [] denotes greatest integer function.

My attempt:
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n!e -[n!e]= \{n!e\}$ where ${x}$ means fractional part of $x$ .

From calculator i observed that $n!e$ is coming closer to integer value when $n$ is very large so $l$ may equal to zero. please help me how to approach this problem?

Comment: Use the series for $e$ and split the sum into first $n+1$ terms and the remaining terms.

Comment: $e$ is irrational, so $l$ is never zero.

Comment: Use KaviRamaMurthy hint. Then use $\frac{n!}{(n+i)!} < \frac{1}{n^i}$ for integer positive $i$.